# Best way to check default value of collections (List ,Set and Map) in java

Tags: java, if-statement, collections

What is the best way to check default value of collections (List ,Set and Map) in java ?

Example :

```
List l = new ArrayList();
Map m = new HashMap();
Set s = new HashSet();
```

### Condition check:

Which case it's better either `isEmpty()` or `null` ?

```
if (l.isEmpty() || l==null){
}
```

Comment: Stating the obvious: `== null` tests for nullity and `isEmpty()` tests for emptiness (of a non-null collection)...

Comment: It's easy. Since you're not evil, you don't initialise your objects to null. So `l==null` is never useful, because your objects are **never** null. Right?

Comment: `c.isEmpty()` usually calls `c.size()` implicitly, so you can just `c.size() == 0`

Comment: @SashaSalauyou most IDEs will then yell at you to use isEmpty() because its cleaner ;)

Comment: @Gimby sure. `isEmpty()` is the best option.

Comment: and one more exotic option where null-check is not necessary: `if (Collections.emptyList().equals(l))`

Comment: @SashaSalauyou now I'm wondering: what is the most exotic way to test for emptiness of a Java list ?

Comment: @Nico `if (Objects.toString(l).equals("[]"))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, I recommend you should swop your tests around:

```
if (l==null || l.isEmpty()){ }
```

This way, if the collection was not initialised, the **or** would prevent NullPointerException

Comment: It is generally recommended to make sure your collections are not null so you don't have to clutter your code with `list != null`.

Comment: Just now i debugged ,If List l = null; then condition is l==null and for isEmpty case List l = new ArrayList();  if(l.isEmpty()) is right.